# How to wait for angular.foreach to end?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want angular.forEach to finish first and then update bulkUpdateCheck to false.

```
           function bulkUpdate(curritems) {            
           
            $scope.bulkUpdateCheck = true;

             angular.forEach(curritems, function (item) {
                   // multiple calls 
                 });
        $scope.bulkUpdateCheck = false;
        }
```

Comment: What happens inside your `forEach()`? `forEach()` itself is a synchronous function. Javascript always waits for it.

Comment: there are multiple async calls inside that but they kept executing in the background.
"$scope.bulkUpdateCheck = false;" this statement is after the foreach

Answer (score 2):

I think your loop should complete before setting bulkUpdateCheck to true

Problem is, "multiple calls" that you are making, might be asynchronous.
So things that are inside your loops needs to end.

Assuming you have asynchronous calls inside your forEach, you should

```
  async function bulkUpdate(curritems) {            
       
        $scope.bulkUpdateCheck = true;
        let multipleCalls = [] // this will keep all your promises
         angular.forEach(curritems, function (item) {
               // change this to promise you are using
               const promise = Promise.resolve(3);                 
               multipleCalls.push(promise)
         });
         await Promise.all(multipleCalls)
         $scope.bulkUpdateCheck = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in `$q.all()` which will initialize a digest when it resolves.

Pass an array of `$http` request promises to it that you create using `Array#map()`

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('main', ($scope, $q, $http, $timeout) => {
    const api_url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/';
    const todoIds = [1, 3, 6, 9, 12];

    bulkUpdate(todoIds);

    $scope.todos = [];


    function bulkUpdate(curritems) {
      $scope.bulkUpdateCheck = true;
      // map arry of request promises
      const reqPromises = curritems.map(n => {
        return $http.get(api_url + n).then(res => res.data);
      })
      // runs when all requests resolved
      $q.all(reqPromises).then(data => {
        // extra delay for demo to see visual difference
        $timeout(() => {
          $scope.bulkUpdateCheck = false;
          $scope.todos = data;
          console.log(data)
        }, 1500)
      })
    }



  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
  <div ng-if="bulkUpdateCheck">Loading...</div>

  <div ng-repeat="item in todos">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.completed" /> {{item.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```